# A Roslyn bug? On non-shared member, I'm getting error that I'm using 'shared member initializer'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, compiler-errors, visual-studio-2015, roslyn

Have the following trivial code:

```vb
Class A

    Private value As Integer = 1

    Sub Action(Optional param1 As Integer = value)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Visual Studio complains about default value (`value`) with error **BC30369**:

> Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.

**Is this really the right error for this case? The method is not shared.**

In Visual Studio 2012 or 2013, the error in the same case is

> Constant expression is required.

what absolutely makes sense.

Comment: That's strange, I got "Constant Expression is Required"

Comment: Yes, not using VS2015 but 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After additional research I think that there is a problem in order of checks made by compiler.

If I change the code, making `value` member **`Shared`**, I get correct result: Error **BC30059**

> Constant expression is required.

Since nothing except constants can be placed into default value of **Optional** clause, check for the above **BC30059** ("Constant expression is required.") should be obviously made "earlier" than the check for **BC30369** (shown in question).

I created [bug report at Microsoft Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1645946/check-for-bc30059-should-be-made-before-check-for-bc30369).